# Batch or PowerShell command to get the names of all the open applications in Windows

Tags: batch-file, powershell, ms-office, taskmanager

We have a command line utility which opens MS Office documents on a server and converts them to PDF.  For Office documents which have a macro in them, a security warning message will pop up and the utility will not proceed to complete the job until someone enables the macro.

For example, the warning message dialog box for a Visio file has the title "Microsoft Visio Security Notice". We need to click on the enable button.

This title is displayed in the Application pane in the Windows Task Manager, but not in the process list.

I want to write a utility to notify me when this occurs.

Could you please let me know what batch or PowerShell command can be used to read/search the task list based on names (i.e., get all the names of applications as displayed in Application pane in the Windows Task Manager).

I have tried tasklist and get-process.  They give information regarding the processes but not the details of the application window title.

Please could you share a way to get the list of application window names or a way to check if there is a security warning open through a script.

Comment: FYI, in newer versions of Office this warning is not displayed in a dialog box.  It is displayed in an info bar (along with an enable button) near the top of the app's main window.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proof of concept. You could implement email functionality or triggers if you need. But really, if you know the window title it's fairly easy to manipulate.

```
$vischk = get-process | where-object {$_.mainwindowhandle -ne 0 -and $_.MainWindowTitle -eq "Microsoft Visio Security Notice"} | select-object name, mainwindowtitle

  if (!($vischk)) 
  {
  Write-Warning "Security notice not present"
  } else {
  Write-Warning "This is where you'd do your scripting"
  }
```

Comment: This give the name of the utility or the process not the window name. For example open google.com in IE and go to Task manager Applications panel, you will see google as the task name. when we see the process it shows only iexplorer.exe. I am tring to search for the google in the application panel.

Answer (score 2):

The information you are seeing in the TaskManager (well at least the one on Win8) is likely pulled from either the FileVersionInfo's Product or Description fields e.g.:

```
Get-Process | % {$_.MainModule} | ft Product,Description
```

BTW if you are looking for a dialog box window title, MainWindowTitle for the process isn't going to help you.  You will need to be able to find a window which you can use the [WASP](http://wasp.codeplex.com/) module to do. And if it is a newer version of Office, the primary apps are no longer using dialog boxes for security warnings about enable macros, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the WASP, I may have to explore it.